# nested sql query which is grouped by and limited rows returned for each group

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Trying to get the right query to look through my table which looks like this:

```
id    fromName    toName    messages
1     user1       me        .......
2     user2       me        .......
3     user1       me        .......
4     user1       me        .......
5     user3       me        .......
6     user2       me        .......
```

What I want to do is get an array which has all the messages from user1 in an array, user2 in an array, user3...etc.  I had a query that did that:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toName='$to' OR fromName='$to' order by id desc");
$messages = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $messages[$row['fromName']][] = $row;
}
```

Now I want to put a limit on how many rows it gets back...for example a limit of 2 rows from all users.  Do I need a nested query using "group by"?  This query isn't working:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toName='$to' OR fromName='$to' group by fromName order by id desc limit 2");
//or this one
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toName='$to' OR fromName='$to' AND id IN(SELECT * FROM messages group by fromName)");
$messages = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $messages[$row['fromName']][] = $row;
}
```

Hope this isn't too difficult to solve....Thanks in advance!

Comment: group by does not solve this problem since it will only return one row and you are not likely to get all the messages. More over without aggregate function using group by is of no sense. You can run one query with the condition and with the loop can generate the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use your original query and run a count on the array before assigning another.

```
if(count($messages[$row['fromName']]) < 2)
    $messages[$row['fromName']][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: wow, it was that easy...I'm not sure why I was overthinking it.  Thanks so much for that!

Answer (score 0):

You should really use `GROUP BY` in your query to get results. You will not need to iterate through the results and formulate an array.

Updated code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toName='$to' OR fromName='$to' GROUP BY fromName");
$senderMessages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Comment: Group by only gives me one row for each.  user2410835's answer gave me exactly what I needed, and I didn't need to change much code.